# Where can I find more information about how to create filters on frequency domain?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, filter-design, frequency-domain

I'm newbie and I'm very interested in filtering images on frequency domain.

I haven't found a lot filters on frequency domain and I wondering how can I create new ones.

How can I create new ones? Such as, and this is only an example, a filter to remove regions on an image with a certain colour.

Related question: [Remove brighter regions in an image on frequency domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62670/remove-brighter-regions-in-an-image-on-frequency-domain)

Comment: Hi! This looks like a very open question. Do you have an understanding on what filtering, linear filtering, frequency domain, and Fourier transforms mean? What have you researched and developed so far?

Comment: @Juancho, I'm going to work with MRI files.

Comment: @Juancho. Thanks for your comment. Where can I find more information about how to create filters to frequency domain?